# SUM multiple Measures in CUBEVALUE

Tags: excel, formula, cube

I have tried multiple different functions CUBESET , CUBEVALUE etc., but I cant seem to find a way to SUM multiple Measures within the same formula. Any tips on how to get this done? I've searched extensively but couldn't find a way

The Idea would be something of the following (but this doesn't work)

`CUBEVALUE("Connection",Period,Filter1,Filter2,CUBESET("Connection","{Measure1,Measure2}"))`

This is required to avoid:

`=CUBEVALUE("Connection",Period,Filter1,Filter2,Measure1)+
CUBEVALUE("Connection",Period,Filter1,Filter2,Measure2)"`

Comment: have you tried: `=SUMPRODUCT(CUBEVALUE("Connection",Period,Filter1,Filter2,{Measure1,Measure2}))`

Comment: that doesnt work unfortunately