# Using OR() in CUBEVALUE()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to build a CUBEVALUE() formula, with one of the filters being an OR() statement. I have searched the web, and only thing similar is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341668/sum-multiple-measures-in-cubevalue) unanswered question.

I have the following COUBEVALUE() formula of the format:

`CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","measure","month","filter")`

The desired is something like:

`CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","measure","month",OR("filter1","filter2","filter3"))`

This is to prevent having to sum all the variations of the CUBVALUE filters, i.e.

`CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","measure","month","filter1") + CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","measure","month","filter2")` etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a small markdown sample of a pivot table you are using for testing purposes?

Comment: @JvdV I have managed to solve, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have found **an** answer for this, so for anyone else who faces this challenge, formula format below:

`CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel","measure","month","filter1",CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel","filterA","filterB","filterC"))`

Where `filter1` is a 'constant' filter, and filters A,B, and C are variations of a filter within a given field. Using the `CUBESET` seems to replicate the `OR` required.